# How to add Keystonejs to an existing Express App

Tags: node.js, express, keystonejs

please I need help with Keystonejs, and I have just created a web app, now I want to create an admin platform for the App. after searching for the best CMS I found out that Keystonejs is more compatible with Heroku and Heroku is where I am hosting my application, so I decided to go with it.

My challenge now is how to integrate Keystonejs to an existing Express app, most of the examples that I saw online are how to use keystone without expressJs. and it generates a bunch of folders and files as it's own server, which is very confusing to me. my background is Rails, and Rails ActiveAdmin allows us to generate the admin panel after creating the model.

If anyone knows a tutorial or good documentation on how to integrate Keystonejs to an existing Express App, please do help me